# jQuery cannot find custom attribute

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

jQuery cannot find my custom attribute on a drop down menu I have a similar one just one line above it that works great, but this keeps giving me an undefined.

***jQuery***

```
$('#admin_student_school_select').change('click',function(){
var school_student = $(this+':selected').attr('school_student');
$('#admin_student_content_details')
  .html(ajax_load)
  .load(loadUrl,"form_being_submitted=admin_page_list_student&school="+school_student);
});
```

***HTML***

```
<select id="admin_student_school_select">
    <option>Select a School</option>
    <option school_student="1">Riverside Community College</option>
    <option school_student="2">Victor Valley College</option>
    <option school_student="3">Cal State San Bernardino</option>
    <option school_student="4">Craffton College</option>
    <option school_student="5">San Bernardino Community</option>
</select>
```

The script behind the ajax call works. I've echoed out results.

Comment: What does `$(this+':selected')` evaluate to? Isn't `this` in that context a DOM element?

Comment: Could you tell us which variable is "undefined"?

Comment: The school_student. It can't find the school_student attribute value.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting this error: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSelectElement]:selected` **?!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is invalid:

```
$('#admin_student_school_select').change('click',function(){
```

What is it, a `click` or a `change` event?!

---

**Update:**

`$(this+':selected')` isn't a valid selector...use this:

```
var school_student = $(':selected', this).attr('school_student');
```

Comment: @Cjueden. I updated the answer.`$(this+':selected')` isn't a valid selector. What are you trying to select?

Comment: I want the school_student attribute value of what ever is selected in the drop-down menu

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `$(this+':selected')` would return anything useful.

Try:

```
$('#admin_student_school_select').change(function(){
   var school_student = $(':selected', this).attr('school_student');
   // rest of your code
});
```

Comment: You're right! it causes an error. but you can improve the selector with this: `$(':selected', this).attr('school_student');`

Comment: **+1** it causes this sort of error: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSelectElement]:selected`

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$('#admin_student_school_select').change(function(){
     var school_student = $(this).val();
});

<select id="admin_student_school_select">
    <option value="0">Select a School</option>
    <option value="1">Riverside Community College</option>
    <option value="2">Victor Valley College</option>
    <option value="3">Cal State San Bernardino</option>
    <option value="4">Craffton College</option>
    <option value="5">San Bernardino Community</option>
</select>
```